# Compile time warnings

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c-preprocessor

Does any one know how to specify user defined warnings for #pragma warning directive in VS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#pragma message ("Message")
```

See [How to use the #pragma message to generate user-defined warning messages in Visual C++](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/155196).

`#pragma warning` is not used to specify user defined warnings but to modify the behavior of built-in compiler (warning) messages.

Comment: @Bertrand Thank you for your answer. I've asked for #pragma warning because when I've typed in VS #pragma warning("Some message") I got the message from compiler:Warning 1 warning C4615: #pragma warning : unknown user warning type So I thought that I can somehow specify user defined warnings as the message from compiler suggests.

Comment: @Bertrand also when I've checked it it seems that second line in this example is surplus, what is your opinion?

Comment: No, it's not. `__STR1__(x)` _evaluates_ the parameter, and `__STR2__(x)` _stringifies_ it. If you just use `__STR2__(__LINE__)`, it will just return `"__LINE__"`.

Comment: @Bertrand no, I've deleted second line and changed in third line STR2 to STR1 and it works as with second line.

Comment: @Bertrand it works in VS2010 if you want I can make mov file and post it to you.